# Paint that will feel like tire rubber

Tags: painting, paint

I have a plastic trophy (of a big tire) that I would like to paint. For the actual tire part of the trophy, it would be cool if it felt like a tire (rubbery).

Is there a type of paint, that when dry, will feel like tire rubber?

Answer (score 13):

A product by the brand name [PlastiDip](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=plastidip&ref=nb_sb_noss)™ exists in spray-on and brush on or dip form. It's somewhat rubbery and is often used as grips for tool handles. Available at the Amazon link in various colors and application types.

I've used it in dip form to encase lead "muffins" to be used as fabric weights, protecting the surfaces from marking and any possibility of hazardous material transfer, but for your tire idea, a well masked hub sprayed with PlastiDip will certainly provide a tire rubber feel. Image from linked site:

[image: PlastiDip]

Comment: I've only found Plasti Dip Craft at my local crafts store. The product seems to be the same, but only comes in spray form.

Answer (score 7):

Liquid electrical tape will do the job. However it's pretty thick though and globs on so it will be challenging to have the underlying texture not be covered up.

Alternatively, you could try mixing in fine rubber powder filler with regular black paint, resin or whatever. Make sure to do plenty of trials before putting it on your final workpiece.

Comment: Although obvious +1 for _"Make sure to do plenty of trials before putting it on your final workpiece."_ this advice applies to any solution you go with, "individual results may vary"

Answer (score 6):

You could use **black liquid latex** that is sold as body paint. It is natural latex that you can brush or pour on and it will give you an actual rubber coating. I have played with the stuff and it is a lot of fun, dries pretty fast and is real rubber so will definitely give you the feel of a rubber tire.

Using an acrylic primer as a base layer may help to get it to adhere better and that is also available in black (though the latex is opaque it cannot hurt to match the color). A quick search online shows a variety of brands, often sold as fetish item but also as makeup/fashion product.

Comment: Not supposed to recommend brands in the answers, so it doesn't turn the platform into an advertising site... but this product looks perfect: https://www.reynoldsam.com/product/hx-body-latex/

Comment: I believe it's okay to cite a brand (perhaps not link to a seller, though) in an answer, as long as it's clear you're a critical consumer and/or have pertinent experience using it. But see also [here](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28/is-it-ok-to-cite-brand-shop).